# Create a password encrypted and store it in sqlite to use in authentication

Tags: c#, winforms, saltedhash

I have a WinForms application, with login form, and I want to store the username and password encrypted in a SQLite database. I saw that I can use salt and hash, but I don't know how to encrypt the password in the code, and compare it when we authenticate.

Any help please?

Comment: If you are using encryption to protect a password you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to take the username and password (the password from a masked text box, preferably with a second box for confirmation) salt it, and create a hash from the password, and then insert the plaintext username and salted hash of the password in to the database. You can then verify the users password in future by comparing the database stored version with a salted (same salt!) hash of what the user enters.

Note that each user should have their own salt which you randomly generate for that user when they create their account. (This is more secure that a global salt value which a hacker could discover).

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164107.aspx). It pretty much covers all the bases, but **don't use SHA-1** as recommended in the article. You want a slow hash function that is computationally expensive such as BCrypt, or PBKDF2 (which is included in .NET). See ["What makes a good hash function for passwords"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-makes-a-hash-function-good-for-password-hashing). (Thanks @CodeInChaos for pointing this out).

You can use [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) in System.Security.Cryptography to create the salted hash of the password, PBKDF2 style.

```
byte[] salt = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray[];
Rfc2898DeriveBytes saltedHash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("P@$$w0rd", salt, 1000);
```

A good rule of thumb is that the number of iterations should cause the hashing operation to take about a second.

Comment: -1 because the code in the article is weak. Single iteration SHA1 is simply too fast.

Comment: @Ostorlabi I've edited my example to point you at PBKDF2 - included in the .NET framework so more trustworthy than a third party solution.

Comment: @Idlemind thank you Idlemind, one more question, now i have to store the username and the saltedHash or the the salt (byte[] salt = saltedHash.Salt;) in the database? and what i must compare?

Comment: @Ostorlabi you will store the username, salt and saltedhash in the database. When the user logs in, hash the password they provide with the salt for that user and then compare the result. If the two hashes are equal, the user has provided the correct password.

Answer (score -1):

You need to storage the hashed password and the salt in the database. Use a **random salt** for each user (A GUID should be fine)
You can hash your passwords with something like that:

Remember to add the `using System.Security.Cryptography;` namespace.

```
    public static string ComputeHash(string passwordPlainText, string saltString)
    {
        // Convert plain text into a byte array.
        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltString);

        // Convert plain text into a byte array.
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        // Allocate array, which will hold plain text and salt.
        byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes =
                new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];

        // Copy plain text bytes into resulting array.
        for (int i = 0; i < plainTextBytes.Length; i++)
            plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainTextBytes[i];

        // Append salt bytes to the resulting array.
        for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
            plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainTextBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];

        // Because we support multiple hashing algorithms, we must define
        // hash object as a common (abstract) base class. We will specify the
        // actual hashing algorithm class later during object creation.
        HashAlgorithm hash;

        hash = new SHA256Managed();

        // Compute hash value of our plain text with appended salt.
        byte[] hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);

        // Create array which will hold hash and original salt bytes.
        byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = new byte[hashBytes.Length +
                                            saltBytes.Length];

        // Copy hash bytes into resulting array.
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            hashWithSaltBytes[i] = hashBytes[i];

        // Append salt bytes to the result.
        for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
            hashWithSaltBytes[hashBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];

        // Convert result into a base64-encoded string.
        string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashWithSaltBytes);

        // Return the result.
        return hashValue;
    }
```

You can change `SHA256Managed` for any other supported hash algorithm.

**Update**: I think you need to understand the concept first. I'll try to explain it:

Before login you need to have the users created in your database. To create them you need username and password.

1. Generate a random SALT, `Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` for example.
2. Now you add this salt to your password and hash the result, the meaning of this is increase the security of your password against brute force attacks. (This step can be done with the function `string ComputeHash(string passwordPlainText, string saltString)` I posted before.
3. Save username(provide by user), salt(guid) and password(result of computeHash) in the database.
4. Login using the table with the user data!

Comment: First,thank you for your answer, I'm newer in this thread, so i have a form of login (currently, i have one userlogin and psw in the code and i compare with what the user enter), if i want to use what you propose, how should i process?

Comment: @Ostorlabi I explained the concept behind this in the answer.

Comment: -1 for using single iteration hashing. Use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.